# Do bad-quality questions on the front page actually impact the company?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I've been seeing a lot more bad-quality posts across the network, a lot of which goes undeleted. (Most of these questions should be on SO.) I know this is because of the strike.

How is this actually affecting MSE and SO (and the rest of the sites?) Does it have any impact on visits/answers/questions? Is it driving away high-rep users who are getting sick of it? Is it encouraging people to join (or leave) the strike?

Comment: Surely it lowers the reputation of the site as a repository of high-quality questions and answers somewhat. As for a quantification, some of your questions might be answerable by suitable queries of the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It will affect search engine ranking. The more spam and AI trash that gets added to the network, the lower the ranking. Which in turn will affect traffic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is probably negligible impact in the short-term, since the company's income is from showing advertisements, and the vast proportion of page views come from external search engines, not via the front page. Search engine results will be mostly unaffected by the strike; perhaps there will be more bad questions showing up in search results, or perhaps some search engines use question scores on SE sites as a measure of relevance, but I think generally search engines are good at finding relevant content, and the vast proportion of that relevant content existed before the strike and is unaffected by it.

The potential impacts you mention (driving away answerers and high-rep users) are second-order effects which would be difficult to measure, because people leave SE sites for all sorts of reasons, and we don't necessarily know how many would have left if the strike weren't happening. But anyway, if long-time users will leave the site because of a flood of unmoderated low-quality questions, that could be after a month or a few months ─ the people with the greatest commitment to a site will be the slowest ones to leave ─ so I wouldn't expect to see a huge impact immediately.

Comment: They do care about returning visitors, because their investors do. If you explore a new site and see only junk, you are unlikely to return again, or even click on search engine results for that site.

Comment: @tripleee Sure, but since most visitors never see the front page, the contents of the front page don't affect whether they return.

Comment: Sure they do if they follow a search link and then wonder what else is here.

Comment: @tripleee If they did that then they would, yes. Overwhelmingly, they don't.

Comment: It would be cool if someone could write a SEDE query to see how visits were effected by the strike.

Comment: I'm sure there are many who don't, but this is still an important use case. How else do you imagine the site attracts new regular users?

Comment: "but I think generally search engines are good at finding relevant content" Disagree with this part, from prior experience trying to find the right duplicate closure target for easy, constantly-asked questions.

Comment: "Search engines" here meaning Google and the like, not Stack Overflow's search.